# How can a Goa'uld be extracted from its host and who can do it?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, goauld

I'm writing a fanfic story that is based off *Stargate SG-1* and I cannot find this information.

How can a Goa'uld be extracted from its host and who can do it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackExchange!  I've cleaned your question up a little bit, so that it is a better fit for our Q&A format.  Things like punctuation, grammar, and capitalization are important here (as well as in fanfics) :-)  Feel free to make further revisions or to revert if you like.

Answer (score 12):

It has never been explained how, but the removal process is exceedingly difficult.  The symbiote can and will kill the host if it is subject to removal and a dead symbiote (unless it takes extraordinary steps to prevent it) kills the host automatically.

The Tok'Ra and Tollan showed evidence of technology which could remove the symbiote safely (though the Tok'Ra's process was not perfect, it had a significant element of risk).  It can be assumed that the Asgard could do it as well, given their medical expertise.  It is safe to assume that ascended beings could remove symbiotes, but it is not known if Priors can do so.

As of the end of *SG-1*, no other species had demonstrated this ability, and it had never been done on Earth.

Comment: For the record, the Tollan used the Tok'Ra for the removal processes. I had to re-watch the series to catch it...

Comment: Well, it HAS been done on earth, but ultimately unsuccessfully, as it only removed the body of the symbiote - it still had complete control of the person's (Kowalsky's) body, as it had 'bonded' with the host.

Comment: It's probably safe to assume nanoscale replicators could do it, too, were they so inclined, just by deconstructing the Goa'uld inside the host.

Comment: In Stargate Atlantis there is also an episode where Caldwell gets a symbiote removed using Asgard beaming technology.

Comment: Thor's hammer uses asgard beaming technology to remove symbiotes as well. It is also significantly easier to remove a willing symbiote.

Comment: I'm a necromancer on this one, but its highly likely the Nox could do it too. With the ability to bring the dead back to life it doesn't matter if the host dies during removal. If they can heal you from death then getting a goauld out would be easy

Answer (score 9):

The Tok'Ra use a [Symbiote Extractor](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Symbiote_extractor) with a needle-like device attached to it that *appears* to teleport the Goa'uld into a holding container. This process is seen during the [Extraction Ceremony](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Extraction_Ceremony) in [*Stargate Continuum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate:_Continuum).

There is a clip of the process on YouTube: